# Can't connect to Apace Kafka inside neo4j user-defined procedure

Tags: java, apache-kafka, neo4j

I've created a user-defined stored procedure and I am trying to produce messages to Kafka inside the procedure. And I am getting the following error:

> [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Here is my code and it works perfectly when I run it in a sample project

```
class KafkaProducer(topic: String, message: String) {
    init {
        val properties = Properties()

        properties[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9092"
        properties[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name
        properties[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name

        val producer = KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties)

        val record = ProducerRecord(topic, "key", message)

        producer.send(record)

        producer.flush()
        producer.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running Kafka on the same server as your Neo4j server? If not, obviously you need to change the address. Also, [neo4j streams exists already](https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/), so why do you need this?

Comment: Yes I am running them on a docker container,  neo4j streams is deprecated on version 4.3, and the Kafka Connect plugin on confluent is only availble

Comment: 1) localhost of neo4j docker container, obviously is not Kafka 2) Deprecated doesn't mean it won't work. The one "on Confluent" is the same thing I linked to